# Google Drive SDK, fetching data on when the file was shared and when the file was last accessed

Tags: file, google-drive-api, external

I'm trying to fetch some data about externally shared files, however I'm having some troubles as it looks like the API doesn't support that.

I'm able to create a list of externally shared files within our organization by using the API and setting the service object's `sub` parameter to each employee's e-mail address (otherwise it just fetches the files owned by the service account).

I also need to retrieve the date when the file was shared externally (which something I didn't find in the returned data) and when the file was a last accessed. The latter one, I'm able to use `lastViewedByMeDate` to see when the file was accessed by the current user (`sub=someuser@example.com`), but not if it was accessed by whomever it is externally shared with.

Is it possible to fetch that data via the API? Perhaps there are some work-arounds?

Thanks.

Comment: With the Activities API you can track the actions done to Drive like when the permissions of a file changed (when it was shared) https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/reference/activities/list. You can also get these activities and also the "view" activity using the Reports API with Drive. Although this report is only available for Google App Unlimited accounts: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list

Comment: Thanks! This looks like what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Apps Activity API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/reference/activities/list) solved it for me. Thanks to [Gerardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4044241/gerardo)!

Note: if you're using Python, the `drive.fileId` parameter in the docs should be `drive_fileId` in your script.