# Find when a file within Google Drive was last accessed by any user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to fetch data around when files stored within Google Drive were last accessed by any user to aid with applying data retention policies.

The `lastViewedByMeDate` property is fine for telling me about a specific user, but with thousands of users on the platform, it is not workable to request this data for each user on every document.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998028/google-drive-sdk-fetching-data-on-when-the-file-was-shared-and-when-the-file-wa) suggests the activity API, but according to [this article by Google](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7061566?hl=en) that would only inform me if a file has been opened in the last 180 days. This is not a workable solution when looking at applying retention policies based upon the user of a document over a number of years.

Is there any other solution I am missing? It seems like a fairly reasonable thing to try and achieve!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve such a functionality you might want to consider setting up Google Workspace Audit Logs. These logs provide detailed information about user activity, including file access, sharing, and modifications.

See [Audit logs for Google Workspace](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/gsuite-audit-logging)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google Drive does not provide a direct way to fetch the last accessed date for all users for each file, primarily due to privacy and performance considerations.

However, you could audit Logs in the Google Workspace Admin console, which provides audit logs that might give you some insights into user interactions with Drive files. However, this approach has limitations regarding the depth of historical data available and might not directly provide "last accessed" timestamps for all files by all users.

You can also use Reports API, which allows you to access activity reports, including Drive activity programmatically. While it offers more flexibility than manually checking the Admin console, it still focuses on events (like view, create, edit) rather than providing a straightforward "last accessed by any user" timestamp.